# Find functions in sympy expression

Tags: python, sympy

I am looking for a robust way of finding functional parameters in a Sympy expression. For example, in the example below, how can one retrieve `f` from `operator`?

```
import sympy

x, y = sympy.symbols('x y')
f = sympy.Function('f')
operator = x*f(x, y).diff(x) + y*f(x, y)

print(operator.free_symbols)
# prints {x, y}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `expr.atoms(class)` returns the set of all objects in `expr` that are instances of that class. So,

```
operator.atoms(sympy.Function)
```

will return `f(x, y)`. If you wish to ignore the arguments of the function, use

```
[a.func for a in operator.atoms(sympy.Function)]
```

(For a SymPy object `a`, `a.func` is its "function" part and `a.args` is its "arguments" part.)

Note that if `operator` included, say, `sin(x)`, that would be included by the above code too. To return only *undefined* (not built-in) functions, replace `sympy.Function` by `sympy.function.AppliedUndef` as the class selector in `atoms`.